# sql rounding value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been successful at rounding my value to one decimal point, but I would like to trim off the multitude of trailing zeros.  For example, this:

```
ROUND(SUM(Duration),1)
```

...ends up giving me:

```
16.9000000000000000
```

how do I trim all those trailing zeros.

mssql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `round` function rounds the number, but it leaves the data type unchanged:

```
ROUND(3.14,1) --> 3.10
```

By casting a number to `numeric(x,1)`, you both round it and change it's data type to single digit precision:

```
CAST(3.14 as numeric(6,1)) --> 3.1
```

For your query, such a cast could look like:

```
select cast(sum(duration) as numeric(6,1))
```

But the eventual display format depends on the client.  SQL Server Management Studio will display `numeric(x,1)` with one digit behind the dot, but it is free to display it in another way.  Formatting a number is best done client side, outside of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
CONVERT(Decimal(9, 1), ROUND(SUM(duration), 1))
```

The second parameter of the DECIMAL data type is the precision - `1` will give you a single digit after the decimal point.